# how to add pull to update in HookWidget's SliverList

Tags: flutter

I am learing Flutter to write a simple app, today I encount a problem. This is my source code of pull to refresh:

```
    import 'package:animations/animations.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';
import 'package:flutter_icons/flutter_icons.dart';
import 'package:flutter_slidable/flutter_slidable.dart';
import 'package:hooks_riverpod/hooks_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:Cruise/src/component/compact_tile.dart';
import 'package:Cruise/src/component/item_card.dart';
import 'package:Cruise/src/component/item_tile.dart';
import 'package:Cruise/src/component/loading_item.dart';
import 'package:Cruise/src/common/helpers.dart';
import 'package:Cruise/src/models/Item.dart';
import 'package:Cruise/src/page/stories_page.dart';
import 'package:Cruise/src/page/story_page.dart';
import 'package:Cruise/src/common/view_manager.dart';
import 'package:pull_to_refresh/pull_to_refresh.dart';

class StoryList extends HookWidget {
  const StoryList({
    Key key,
    @required this.ids,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final List<int> ids;

  _getViewType(ViewType type, Item item) {
    switch (type) {
      case ViewType.compactTile:
        return CompactTile(item: item);
        break;
      case ViewType.itemCard:
        return ItemCard(item: item);
        break;
      case ViewType.itemTile:
        return ItemTile(item: item);
        break;
      default:
        return ItemCard(item: item);
        break;
    }
  }



  RefreshController _refreshController =
  RefreshController(initialRefresh: false);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final currentView = useProvider(viewProvider.state);

    return SmartRefresher(
        onRefresh:(){
          _refreshController.refreshCompleted();

        },
        onLoading: (){
          List<int> items = [1];
          setState(() {
            ids:items;
          });
          _refreshController.loadComplete();
        },
        child:SliverList(
          delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
            (context, index) {
              return Consumer(
                (context, read) {
                  return read(storyProvider(ids[index])).when(
                    loading: () => LoadingItem(count: 1),
                    error: (err, trace) => Text("Error: $err"),
                    data: (item) {
                      return Slidable(
                        key: Key(item.id.toString()),
                        closeOnScroll: true,
                        actionPane: SlidableScrollActionPane(),
                        actions: <Widget>[
                          IconSlideAction(
                            color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
                            icon: Feather.arrow_up_circle,
                            onTap: () => handleUpvote(context, item: item),
                          ),
                        ],
                        dismissal: SlidableDismissal(
                          closeOnCanceled: true,
                          dismissThresholds: {
                            SlideActionType.primary: 0.2,
                            SlideActionType.secondary: 0.2,
                          },
                          child: SlidableDrawerDismissal(),
                          onWillDismiss: (actionType) {
                            handleUpvote(context, item: item);
                            return false;
                          },
                        ),
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                          child: OpenContainer(
                            tappable: true,
                            closedElevation: 0,
                            closedColor:
                                Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
                            openColor:
                                Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
                            transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                            closedBuilder:
                                (BuildContext c, VoidCallback action) =>
                                    _getViewType(currentView, item),
                            openBuilder:
                                (BuildContext c, VoidCallback action) =>
                                    StoryPage(item: item),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  );
                },
              );
            },
            childCount: ids.length,
          ),
        ));
  }

}
```

I am trying to add pull to refresh feature in `SliverList`, now how to trigger the update data logic, in this widget? it give me tips `The method 'setState' isn't defined for the type 'StoryList'.`

Comment: I don't see a call o setState in your code. What lime is throwing this error?

Comment: I added the setstate in my question code @RémiRousselet

Comment: Is HookWidget a stateFul or stateless widget?